Finding integral curves to IVPs with accumulation functions
I find it rather elegant that if you have a separable, first-order initial-value problem,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x)}{g(y)}, \qquad y(a) = b$$
then you can implicitly solve it simply by creating two definite integrals (i.e. accumulations functions) based on the initial conditions:
$$\int_{b}^{y} g(s)\,ds = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt$$
In particular, this means that any graphing software which can use numerical integration methods can easily plot integral curves of first-order ODEs. Here is a quick example of what I mean thrown together in Demos:

This got me wondering: can this kind of numerical method of calculating integrals always be used to represent integral curves of first-order differential equations? I know software like Mathematica has other ways of numerically modeling integral curves, but perhaps there is a way to "hijack" the tools used for integration as well?
For example, how could I try to model integral curves of $\frac{dy}{dx} = x + y$ or $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin(xy)$ using definite integrals/accumulation functions? And if I cannot, why is it not possible? Or moreover, is there some criteria other than separability that would allow for such a work around?
